# An array with O(n) inversions

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Trying to figure out what type of  an array consists of at most n inversions with n being the array size. I was thinking an array that is nearly sorted would fall under this case and also an array that is almost completely sorted with the max element and min element switched, for instance..

9 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1

So my thinking is that when an array has at most n inversions, is it safe to say that the array is nearly sorted? Or are there other cases where the array would have at most n inversions and not be nearly sorted.

Comment: That probably depends on your definition of "almost sorted"

Comment: Your example has 8 + 8 = 16 inversions and n = 9. ._. Do you know what an inversion is?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. For instance say we have an array of
3 2 1 6 5 4 9 8 7  this would have 6 inversions so it falls under the O(n) inversions case and I'm assuming it is nearly sorted. I could be wrong. The general problem states to find a way to sort an array with O(n) inversions in theta(n). I was thinking if it is true that an array with O(n) inversion is nearly sorted, then we can just use an insertion sort.

Comment: @user2923281 You're right about that. If an array has at most n inversions then at most n comparisons will need to be made with an insertion sort.

Comment: Ooops I see. a better example would be 9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'least' sorted array (i.e. reverse sorted) has `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n-1 = n(n-1)/2` inversions.

The less inversions an array has, the 'more' sorted it is.

And, since `n` is quite a bit smaller than `n(n-1)/2`, one can probably call an array with `n` inversions 'nearly sorted'.

This array has `n-1` inversions:

```
9 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

In response to your comment, [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort)'s complexity is `O(n + d)`, where `d` is the number of inversions, thus it will run in `O(n)` for `O(n)` inversions.

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling it was dealing with insertion sort, I just needed some clarification that I was on the right track. Again thanks for the clarification.